# I cleaned the fridge and it still smells. What part should I clean / replace?

Tags: cleaning, refrigerator, smell

My last tenant was, to put it mildly, a slob.  I spent several hours cleaning the fridge pictured below, with a steam cleaner and various cleaning products until it looked nearly new.  I then removed the rear of the freezer that housed the fan and cleaned the drain channels there as well (which were in a bit better condition than I expected).

I then added a fresh box of baking soda to both the refrigerator and freezer sections, however after a few days of running the fridge it still smells.

### My refrigerator looks clean, why does it still smell? and how can I fix it?

[image: disgusting freezer]
[image: disgusting fridge]

Comment: While well written, it's an appliance question.

Comment: @Bryce I thought only small home appliances were off topic.

Comment: This is on topic but don't understand the pictures of the initial mess.  Funny though.

Comment: I have dealt with this problem many times as well. I found that Clorox Clean Up does a decent job, sometimes followed by a strong citrus acid type cleaner.

Comment: Have you cleaned the drain pan underneath?  Setting a bowl of white vinegar, and/or activated charcoal in it for several days may help. You can also search for "refrigerator stinks after cleaning" for other ideas.

Comment: There are pretty extensive guides on this topic available via googling.  Basically all manner of substances (tomato, oatmeal, baking soda) supposedly absorb odor.

Comment: @shirlockhomes I used bleach and a steam cleaner; it looks almost brand new on the inside now that I replaced the broken drawer; the smell doesn't seem to be coming from the visible surfaces.

Comment: @getterdun I couldn't' get the pan out, but it doesn't smell from the front with the door closed.  I guess white vinegar might be worth a shot.